# Flutter: Function returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

Not sure why I'm getting null in payload. I want to use payload to determine if my device is registered or not. If registered I'll subscribe to topic. If not I'll do something else. But I am getting null on payload.

Part 1:

```
client.subscribe(registerTopic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
onSub().then((payload) {
  //if(payload == '1')
  print('Payload: $payload');
  client.subscribe(subTopic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
});
```

and then part 2:

```
Future<String> onSub() async {
  client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
    final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload;
    receivedMessage =
        MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
    print(
        '::Change notification:: topic -> <${c[0].topic}>, payload ->  <$receivedMessage> ');
    payload = receivedMessage;
  });

  return payload;
}
```

My output:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Restarted application in 2,501ms.
I/flutter (12404): ::Data connection is available.
I/flutter (12404): ::Mosquitto client connecting....
I/flutter (12404): ::Mosquitto client connected
I/flutter (12404): Payload: null
I/flutter (12404): ::Subscription confirmed -> topic -> registerTopic/registered
I/flutter (12404): ::Subscription confirmed -> topic -> subTopic/control_instruction
I/flutter (12404): ::Change notification:: topic -> <reisterTopic/registered>, payload ->  <1> 
I/flutter (12404): ::Change notification:: topic -> <subTopic/control_instruction>, payload ->  <00010000011000000000>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get null, because `then` had been called before first message was received from `client.updates` You should not use Future. If you want connect after first message, you should use `Stream<String>` instead of `Future<String>`.

Part 1:

```
client.subscribe(registerTopic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
client.updates
  .map<String>(_mapToString)
  .listen((String payload) {
    if (payload == '1') {
      client.subscribe(subTopic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);
    }
  });
```

Part 2:

```
String _mapToString(List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
  final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload;
  receivedMessage = MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
  print(
    '::Change notification:: topic -> <${c[0].topic}>, payload ->  <$receivedMessage> ');
  return receivedMessage;
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Can you suggest me some good tutorials so that I can understand Stream better. I am really new to this. So I am having a hard time understanding everything. Your solution works. But I am not quite sure I understand how it works.

Comment: If you want to understand how it works you should study Reactive Programming. First you should know [Streams from Dart Docs](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams). Than [Intro to Streams](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/fundamentals-of-dart-streams/) and next step ["Manipulating data on the fly"](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxdart-magical-transformations-of-streams/)